# Microservices in .NET Core

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-web-api, microservices

I am working on microservices project in .NET Core which have a structure as given below
[project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g7H0U.png)

In this solution, one is an API Gateway project, which is .NET Core project, and the rest projects under the folder 'microservices' are .NET Web API projects.

I have referenced this article: [microservice-architecture-in-aspnet-core](//codewithmukesh.com/blog/microservice-architecture-in-aspnet-core/)

In this article, they are working with different SQL Server databases for every microservice.
I have only single database for all microservices.

Can anyone guide me in this scenario?

I would like to know where should I put my DbContext file and all the entities to use them in all microservices.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is good rule: if entities in different tables do not interfere with each other, you can place them in single database, but different schemas. Other, more important aspect to consider, is to determine degree of scalability of your system: 1) highload with 10-100 of thouthands RPS? - separate DB per service, definitely. 2) Simple small monitoring system for some facility? - who knows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution for this question after some time of asking this question...

[image: Project structure]

You can add one class library project in that project you can put your `DBContext`, `DBEntities` and `Models` as shown in above project structure image.

After that you can use them in your API projects by giving its reference.

Thank you.

Comment: JFYI this approach is mentioned/suggested at least in two other answers.

Answer (score 2):

Usually using [shared database](https://microservices.io/patterns/data/shared-database.html) is considered anti-pattern in the microservices world. When you decide to use the microservices one of the goals is to achieve as loose coupling between components as possible, the shared database is usually an obstacle on the path to this. If there are serious reasons why you need it - maybe you should reconsider using microservices in the first place.

If you still want/need to use microservices with share database - then you should consider introducing logical split of the database into parts (maybe using schemas) which have no relations between each other and use multiple contexts (one per service).

If the approach is not feasible at this point for some reason (legacy database for example, though I still highly recommend to make it feasible) - then use the standard approach for n-tiered architectures - introduce the separate database project and store context there.

Answer (score 1):

*As [Guru stron pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76685493/4122889) this may not be the best way to go about things, consider this.*

Create a library project (maybe DAL (data access layer)) and reference that in all projects, declare your dbcontext/entities there.

We have the same setup. We even have multiple dbcontexts in one c# project.

[image]
[image]

You can then either keep migrations in a single executable project, or move migrations to the DAL project as well (either is fine afaik);

To use a seperate assembly see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/projects?tabs=dotnet-core-cli

Ex.:

```cs
 services.AddDbContextFactory<WebApiDbContext>(options => 
            options.UseSqlServer(_defaultConnectionString, b =>
            {
                b.MigrationsAssembly(typeof(Initial).Assembly.GetName().Name);
            ...
```

`Ìnitial` is an initial migration file.

A good read when using the ef cli tools is also;
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dbcontext-creation?tabs=dotnet-core-cli

Answer (score 0):

As it is already underlined, sharing a database in microservices architecture should be treated as anti-pattern. Guru Stron has [pointed out common concepts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76685493/308436) on how database should be decomposed.

However, if you decide to go this way, I can foresee a next question that might arise from a problem on how to share data between different context. I believe that Customer entities in the customer microservice need to reference Projects somehow. Storing data in different databases won't allow you referencing it directly. Therefore, you need to introduce a mediator between those microservices. Nowadays, there are multiple tools that can play a role of the mediator, e.g. Apache Kafka, RabbitMQ, Azure Service Bus. Using those tools, you could publish an event from the Product microservice and handle it in the Customer one, so that the latter could apply necessary changes happened in the former.

Honestly, in spite Microservices Architecture is a common trend nowadays, building it correctly is not as an easy task as it might look from the first glance. I would strongly suggest learning a comprehensive guide on the Microsoft website that shares all necessary concepts.
https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/aspnet/microservices-architecture